# In django, what can cause uncatchable exception in object.get()?

Tags: django

If the primary key is found, this code prints 'a' 'b' 'e'.  If not, only 'a' is printed.  What can cause the exception to be swallowed?

```
def foo(request, e_pk):
    try:
        pprint('a')
        facet = models.EntryFacet.objects.get(pk=e_pk)
        pprint('b')
    except models.EntryFacet.DoesNotExist:
        pprint('c ' + sys.exc_info()[0])
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pprint('d ' + sys.exc_info()[0])
    pprint('e')
    return render_to_response(...)
```

Environment: django 1.3, Linux. settings.py has DEBUG = True TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

Comment: Have you done `import sys` - that might be throwing its own error once the `get()` exception is caught?

Comment: If you have `DEBUG` enabled, you should be able to see the exception in your browser.

Comment: sys is imported, and a bare pprint('c') returns the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you try

```
print('c ' + sys.exc_info()[0])
```

it raise TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'type' objects
so you should use:

```
print('c %s' % sys.exc_info()[0])
```

also look at [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Comment: I get the same result with just print('c'), so that's not it.